# Power BI - Can we load ROLES and their associated DAX filter expressions from some EXCEL File?

Tags: excel, powerbi, load, roles, row-level-security

**Hello,**

I got a question about the way we create ROLES in Power BI desktop. The manual ROLES creation process is really hack-tic and time consuming. **I want to ask if there is any way to create/load Power BI ROLES with their DAX filter expressions from some EXCEL file ?**

for reference i am attaching following img
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to create the roles is via the interface at this time. There is no functionality via the API, or by reading the contents/updating inside of the PBIX file (which contains xml, json and other formats).

There is a vote for this functionality on the [Power BI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=eb2b0e18-f2b5-4b10-a9e0-72165f91af0e) site, and a [Power BI Designer API](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=4657bb93-bb25-48c2-9304-26bfd8def58c) here.